# SELECT inside Aggregate Function

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Let's say I have 3 tables like this:

```
class
id
capacity

student
id

student_class
id_student
id_class
```

```
SELECT c.id
FROM student_class sc
JOIN class c
  ON c.id=sc.id_class
JOIN student s
  ON s.id=sc.id_student
HAVING MAX((SELECT(COUNT(sc2.id) FROM student_class sc2 WHERE sc2.id_student=s.id AND sc2.id_course=c.id)/c.capacity))
```

I want to find the course with the highest enrolled/capacity ratio.

Should I write the having clause like this using a select clause inside an aggregate function?

```
HAVING MAX((query that gives me the total number of students enrolled in a course)/course capacity))
```

Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question doesn't really make sense, unless the `MAX()` could return `NULL` or `0`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited providing sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to find the course with the highest enrolled/capacity ratio.

You would use aggregation to calculate the ratio.  Then you can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to return one value.  Note that this returns one row, even if there are ties:

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(*) / c.capacity as ratio
FROM student_class sc JOIN
     class c
     ON c.id = sc.id_class
GROUP BY c.id, c.capacity
ORDER BY ratio DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! So in general it is not possible to use the result of a query inside an aggregate function right?

Comment: @Mizzet . . . It is possible.  It just doesn't do what you want to do.

Comment: In the case of what I wrote, what would that having max clause return me then?

Comment: @Mizzet . . . First, in most databases it would not be allowed because there is no `GROUP BY`.  MySQL extends the use of the `HAVING` clause.  It would return either no rows (if the condition evaluates to 0 or `NULL`) or all rows in other circumstances.